# Why is that unreachable code?

Tags: android, while-loop

I'm generating a question and answers of that randomly. And I want to generate new random arrays and answer options according to those when users chose the correct answer. But it says "unreachable code" when I add a boolean while loop... What is theproblem?

Thanks...

```
final boolean basadon = false;
    while(basadon)

    {
    Random soru = new Random();
    final int[] rastgele = new int[1];
    for (int i=0; i<1; i++)
            {
                rastgele[i]= soru.nextInt(8);
            }

     ArrayList<Integer> cevap = new ArrayList<Integer>();

     for (int k = 0; k <= 7; ++k) 
        {
            cevap.add(k);               
        }

     final Integer[] rastgele2 = new Integer[4];
                if (rastgele[0]!=cevap.get(0))
                {
                rastgele2[0]=cevap.get(0);
                }
                else
                {
                rastgele2[0]=cevap.get(3);
                }
                if (rastgele[0]!=cevap.get(1))
                {
                rastgele2[1]=cevap.get(1);
                } 
                else
                {
                rastgele2[1]=cevap.get(3);
                }
                if (rastgele[0]!=cevap.get(2))
                {
                rastgele2[2]=cevap.get(2);
                } 
                else
                {
                rastgele2[2]=cevap.get(3);
                }                   
                rastgele2[3]=rastgele[0];
                Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(rastgele2)); 



    view.setText(countries.get(rastgele[0]));
    cevap1.setBackgroundResource(heads[rastgele2[0]]);

    cevap1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              

        if (rastgele[0]==rastgele2[0])
        {
            cevap1.setBackgroundResource(heads[8]);
            countries.remove(rastgele[0]);
            basadon=true;
        }
        else {
            cevap1.setBackgroundResource(heads[9]);

        }
        }
    });
    cevap2.setBackgroundResource(heads[rastgele2[1]]);      
    cevap2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              

        if (rastgele2[1]==rastgele[0])
        {
            cevap2.setBackgroundResource(heads[8]);
            countries.remove(rastgele[0]);
            basadon=true;
        }
        else {
            cevap2.setBackgroundResource(heads[9]);

        }
        }
    });
    cevap3.setBackgroundResource(heads[rastgele2[2]]);        
    cevap3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              

            if (rastgele2[2]==rastgele[0])
        {
            cevap3.setBackgroundResource(heads[8]);
            countries.remove(rastgele[0]);
            basadon=true;
        }
        else {
            cevap3.setBackgroundResource(heads[9]);

        }
        }
    });
    cevap4.setBackgroundResource(heads[rastgele2[3]]);
    cevap4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              

            if (rastgele2[3]==rastgele[0])
        {
            cevap4.setBackgroundResource(heads[8]);
            countries.remove(rastgele[0]);
            basadon=true;
        }
        else {
            cevap4.setBackgroundResource(heads[9]);

        }
        }
    });
    }
    } }
```

Comment: it'd be helpful if you told us WHERE in this wall of code you were adding a "boolean loop"

Comment: Look at line 2... the `while(false)` loop will never be entered this way!

Comment: and beside that the number of lines of code can be at least reduced by 3 or 4...

Comment: Any particular reason for having basedon as final ?

Comment: I want to generate new question and answer when users chose the right option.. so it must be return to begin "Random soru = new Random();" again :/

Comment: You need to provide more context for this code. I looks like what you really want to do is move that while loop code into a separate function that the click handler calls.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you start with basedon value as false and later set it to true inside the loop.

So, Change

```
final boolean basedon = false
while (basedon) {
   ....
}
```

to

```
boolean basedon = false;
do {
....
} while (basedon);
```

Answer (score 0):

`while(basadon)` is always false, so you never enter the loop. What you really mean is probably `while(basadon==false)`. Also, don't declare `basalon` as `final boolean` because you want to modify its value later, and that will give error.

Comment: When I write "while(basadon=false)" then it says remove final modifier of basadon. so when use "basadon=true;" it says do final again. ://

Comment: @FıratCihangirKırbay `==`, not `=`.

Comment: If you declare `basadon` as final, you are not allowed to change it. Since you intend to modify this boolean inside the loop, you must remove the word `final` in front of it.

Comment: But then it says change modifier of basadon to final on "basadon=true;"

Comment: Maybe you're including these codes inside a static method. If that is the case try remove the `static` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably complaining because `basadon` is known to be `false` and the body of the `while` loop cannot be reached. You can suppress the complaint by adding this annotation to the method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
```

You might also try removing the `final` modifier from the declaration of `basadon`. That might resolve the issue (but I'm not sure about that).

EDIT I finally noticed that you are trying to modify `basadon` directly from within your click listeners. That obviously won't work if `basadon` is `final`, yet you cannot access local variable unless it is `final`. I suggest you change `basadon` to be a (non-`final`) field of the enclosing class. Then all the warnings and errors should go away.

Comment: Suppressing warnings doesn't solve the actual problem which is that the loop is never entered.

Comment: I remove that, it says change modifier of basadon to final again. :/

Comment: @Juhana - That's not necessarily an actual problem. Sometimes one wants to comment out a section of code for testing purposes (although admittedly it's more common to use an `if` than a `while` block for this).

Comment: @FıratCihangirKırbay - I edited my answer with a suggestion for what to do about this.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring all of those variables as final?
If bsadon for example needs to change from false to true, it can't be final. A final value is exactly that, a constant, it won't change.
Don't declare something as final unless you want it to keep the same value for the entire runtime of your program.

You are saying basadon is always "false", that's what final means, so the compiler is telling you you will never enter the while, since you need it to evaluate "true" to enter.

The expression between () in you while clause, needs to evaluate to true for the code to enter.

Answer (score 0):

To your specific question which you have asked:

```
Why does the compiler give unreachable code warning
```

The answer is that since the condition in while loop is always false, there is no chance that the code in while loop will get executed. The warning is given to indicate that (given the current code situation) you have wasted your effort in typing that portion of code and it is guaranteed never to be executed. To rectify this, you can remove the final modifier from basedon and put a programming logic to set the value of basedon which will decide whether to enter the loop or not. If you want the loop to always run put while(true).

But I believe that what you wanted to ask was how to make the random question and answer generator. For that you'll have to post a bigger chunk of your code (It looks like you are trying to put a loop over a listener callback ?) and phrase your question to ask specific problems (possibly post a separate question).